# How to open cmd as Administrator in Atom-IDE embeded terminal

Tags: cmd, atom-editor

I am using atom for Nodejs-MongoDB development,

to start MongoDB server I need to start `cmd` as `Run as administrator`,
then only server starts.

but when I use atoms default terminal embedded in IDE, it is opened as user and can't be run as admin, unlike we do in linux using `su` or `sudo`,

when I tried `net start MongoDB` command in atoms-terminal it said permission denied.
then how can I run it as admin through atoms terminal?

[image: screenshot of screen]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to open cmd or powershell as admin by default:

1. go to `Start`
2. search `PowerShell`
3. right click on `PowerShell`
4. select `Open file location`
5. go to `Properties` >> `Shortcuts` >> `Advance`
6. check `Run as administrator` option
7. `Apply` >> `Ok`
8. now go to `Start`
9. search `atom`
10. select `open as administrator` and you are running commands as admin through embeded terminal.

Answer (score 0):

if your atom ide uses the powershell terminal, you can open powershell as administrator from start menu, and type this command :
Set-ExecutionPolicy -Scope CurrentUser -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Force